# Change cursor on hovering over a Raphael element

Tags: javascript, css, raphael

A Raphael element is created dynamically (in response to user input, not upon page load). I want to use Raphael's .hover() method to change the cursor to "pointer" (the hand usually used for links) when the user hovers over the object. How can this be accomplished?

(I know that you can use CSS to achieve this effect, but because the DOM element is created via scripting, rather than being built into the page upon load, I don't know if CSS can be applied here, or how it would be if it can be.)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=pointer

https://web.archive.org/web/20160121064823/http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Comment: Just a thought. Instead of creating an event handler, you could just call `el.attr({cursor:'pointer'})`. There's no point setting it and un-setting it on hover because it's the same as if you just set the default cursor of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "cursor" is actually one of the attributes than can be modified with Raphael's .attr() function. So,

```
el.hover(function(){el.attr({'cursor':'pointer'})}, 
  function(){el.attr({'cursor':'default'})}, el, el);
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var paper = Raphael("rect", 400, 400);
var hoverIn = function() {
 // if the context is not stated forcefully, this refers to the element in context.
  // can be any valid cursor types.
  this.attr({"cursor": "pointer"});
};

var hoverOut = function() {
  this.attr({"cursor": "default"});    
}
// simple click callback.
var clickFN = function (){
 alert('Hey you just clicked me :p, Thanks!!!')
};
var cItem = paper.rect(40,40,50,30)
  // attaching the hovering callbacks.
  .hover(hoverIn, hoverOut)
    // these are just additional cosmetics and fuctionalities.
  .attr({
        "fill": "#0ff000"
    })
    .click(clickFN);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.1/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect"></div>
```

or play with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyanGhatak/0gqzvhxe/2/)!

Hey while invoking the .hover function the third and fourth parameters remains optional and used only if you need to change the context in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cursor attribute value for a specific object directly.
Keep it simple! :)

```js
var paper = Raphael("rect", 400, 400);
var myRectangle = paper.rect(40,40,50,30);

myRectangle.attr({
  'cursor':'pointer',
  "fill": "#0ff000"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.1/raphael.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect"></div>
```